# UX Themes for thesis

Tags: responsive, emotion, themes

I'm studying a master degree in User Experience Design and I have to propose a theme for the thesis and I don't have that many experience in the area.

I've read the trending topics of UX for 2017 but at the end I don't know how to relate them to something tangible.

For example: Responsive age design or emotional design. What can I do with those themes?

Could you help me?

Comment: Never having written or read a thesis I don't know if it would be a big enough topic but, talk about how user experience affects the belivability of design. Ever landed on a news site and said "well this looks sketchy" and discounted everything it said. It could tie into the hot topic right now of "fake news".

Answer (score 1):

If you want a challenging theme then go for VR(virtual reality) domain or some other devices where UX field is least explored and there will be lots of fun and you will have great future

Answer (score 0):

I think the best advice is to talk with your professors to see what themes they are interested in. They should know what areas need further exploration. Then, if you are also interested in those areas, then you are more likely to do better. There are lots of unexplored areas in UX regarding artificial intelligence. It’s a hot topic because of Alexa, Siri, and Google’s own AI.